# HttpServletRequest variable with slash vs %2f

Tags: java, spring, web-services, rest

Here is my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value="/test/**", headers="Accept=*/*")
public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<byte[]> getRequest(HttpServletRequest request) 
{
        System.out.println((String) request.getAttribute( HandlerMapping.PATH_WITHIN_HANDLER_MAPPING_ATTRIBUTE ));
}
```

Whenever I want to create `GET`request looking like this: `localhost:8080/test/some/request/given/in` My system out write in console:

`some/request/given/in`

As I want it to. Problem comes when I have instead of slash - `/` symbol `%2F` or `%2f`. When I have those symbols in my path request is not handled by controller at all.

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Do you mean just when the slashes are escaped right next to `test`, or if the escape code appears anywhere in the entire URI?

Comment: I mean when I want to execute Http request looking like this: `localhost:8080/test/some%2frequest%2fgiven`

Comment: Make sure that your `web.xml` is mapping those URLs onto your `DispatcherServlet`, then turn up your logs for `DispatcherServlet` to see what comments it's making when it tries to figure out what controller to use. Also, is there a reason you're not just using a `@RequestParam` for that path part?

Comment: I have done all of it. My logs looks good when I put any request - I mean track is logged. When I put `%2f` i see nothing logged and returned http400

Comment: The error code is very relevant information; please mention such things in future questions. You will see *something* logged if you turn your logs up to `DEBUG` level; the fact that you have them set to a quieter level doesn't mean that there's nothing there.

Comment: @Mithrand1r, why would you use URL encoded slashes in your path? Encoding/decoding should happen only on the data and not on the path.

Comment: @Santosh I would not. honestly. But Client which can use my solution will. It is written in RFC 6960 that client will make GET request to my servlet giving value encoded in base64 ( which allow /)

Comment: @Mithrand1r, which app server you are using ? There should be some app server specific setting for this.

Comment: Actually I am using server which is provided by Spring Tool Suit installer - Vmware vFabric Apache tomcat

Comment: @Mithrand1r, Check my answer bellow. That might help you as mentioned that you are using tomcat.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typically most of the application server will not not treat `%2F` as `/` if `%2F` is found in URL. But as the specs declare `%2F` is one of the ways a path delimiter can be specified, for handling this scenario, tomcat provides system level property

For tomcat, if

```
org.apache.tomcat.util.buf. UDecoder.ALLOW_ENCODED_SLASH = true
```

then  `%2F` and `%5C` will be permitted as path delimiters. [Refer to the documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/systemprops.html). This can be set as `JAVA_OPTS` in tomcat batch files as follows

```
set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% %LOGGING_CONFIG%   -Dorg.apache.tomcat.util.buf.UDecoder.ALLOW_ENCODED_SLASH=true
```

This is **specifically for Tomcat**. I am sure there would be similar arrangement for other application servers as well.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use URL encoder and decoder to send the path params with special chars such as `/` and `-`. In your server side code, you just need to put:

```
String result = URLDecoder.decode(url, "UTF-8");
```

and then fetch the params.

Comment: Where do You recommend me to put this code? Problem is that my controller is not handling the given request so no code insude `getRequest` method is executed..

Comment: If you have spring on the classpath, don't use `java.net.URLDecoder`. Use [`org.springframework.web.util.UriUtils.decode()`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/UriUtils.html) instead. This [blog post](http://blog.lunatech.com/2009/02/03/what-every-web-developer-must-know-about-url-encoding#HandlingURLscorrectlyinJava) outlines the reasons.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're encountering is that the encoded slash characters `%2f` are being placed in the `abs_path` part of the HTTP URL, as defined in section 3.2.1 of [RFC 2616](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt). The grammar for `abs_path`, defined in [RFC 2396](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt), is specifically defined in terms of the US-ASCII character `'/'`, not in terms of the semantic character "slash". If you want to be able to use escaped slash characters for some reason, you need to use a URL with a `query` part (e.g., `/test/?some%2frequest`).

Comment: Well, thank you for support. But unfortunately I met conflict here.. `RFC 6960` Which I am trying to implement says that GET method need to pass `based64` string in my `path variable` not within a querry